# One Object, Multiple Function Calls - Python & Java

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, pipeline

Is there a way to Pipeline an object in Python or Java? I remember doing something like the following before. Here's the pseudocode:

```
with object:
    .function()
    .function1()
    .function2()
```

Where functions would either return nothing and mutate the object or feed the output into the following function.

Comment: Search for method chaining/fluent interface examples in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Object functionx() {
    ...

    return this;
}
```